# Помогите найти ошибку, пожалуйста

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

Браузер  выдает

> Fatal error: Call to a member function select() on a non-object

в строке $query->select

```html
 class ModServiceListHelper {
  public function __construct() 
     {
           parent::__construct(); 
           $this->load->database();
     }
     
 public function getList($params) {
  $db = JFactory::getDbo();
  $query = $db -> getQuery(TRUE);
  
  $guery->select($db->quoteName(array('id', 'price', 'service', 'section', 'state')));
  $query->from($db->quoteName('#__servicelist_'));
  $query->where('state = 1');
  $query->order('service ASC');
  $query->setlimit($params->get('section'));
  
  $db->setQuery($query);
  $result = $db->loadObjectList();
  
  return $result;
 }
}
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку. В административной части модуль работает без нареканий...

Comment: наверно должно быть так:
      $query = $db->getQuery(TRUE);

Comment: Не помогает... Браузер упорно сообщает об ошибке в строке $guery->select($db->quoteName(array('id', 'price', 'service', 'section', 'state')));

Comment: Нашел.... !!! Ура

Comment: действительно, ошибка на строку ниже, однако думал что $obj -> method() работать не будет, но работает